# AES_DECRYPT How do you check value is already decrypted in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, encryption, aes

I want to decrypt fields in my database using sql on mysql but before I decrypt I need to check if the fields can be decrypted.

```
update customer
set name = aes_decrypt(from_base64(name), 'key')
```

If the provided key is wrong or data is invalid the name field will be set to null;

I have tried adding a where clause like below to make sure the field name is not already decrypted but this doesn't work all the time as the aes_decrypt can return null or garbage if the key is incorrect or data is invalid.

```
update customer
set name = aes_decrypt(from_base64(name), 'key')
where aes_decrypt(from_base64(name), 'key') is not null.
```

So how can I check if the returned value is null or "garbage"? Or what other approach is there?

From mysql doc: "it is possible for AES_DECRYPT() to return a non-NULL value (possibly garbage) if the input data or the key is invalid."

garbage example I get: w���� ��Y�'v��Y�m��_

Thanks

Comment: It's somewhat tautalogical, but unless you know what decrypted data might look like, you won't know it's valid. If the unencrypted data was actual random values, then there's no way to tell the difference between the two different sets of random data.

Comment: There is something (application data dictionary) that you can check to find out if a particular table.column is encrypted? Or does the program (and programmer) have to guess? ;-/

Comment: How can you not know if a field is encrypted and if so what key? That is established when the db is designed. Surely you are not mixing encrypted and un-encrypted in the same field

Comment: @RyanVincent The program (and programmer) has to guess.

Comment: @RyanVincent no worries - thanks for trying

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing *raw* ciphertext, follow the lead of version 2 of [Defuse Security's PHP encryption library](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption):

1. [Use authenticated encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly).
2. Use a version tag which tells what library was used as well as what version and any optional configuration information you need to add.
3. Make sure to calculate HMAC(tag || IV || ciphertext) instead of just HMAC(ciphertext).
4. Store the tag, IV/nonce, ciphertext, and MAC together; preferably as a  hex- or base64-encoded string.

Then the question becomes "Do the first N bytes of the string evaluate to a known version tag of my encryption library"?

Comment: "would it be more secure to put the signature at the end?" It literally doesn't matter, but it does make it easier to say SUBSTRING(str, 0, 4) instead of having to calculate based on the length of the string.